# Suds client implementation with multiple different URLs in single call, Possible?

Tags: soap, client, suds

I want to make a SOAP request (which will gives me desired response) to URL2 method which include below structure.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="URL1" xmlns:ns1="URL2">
<soapenv:Header>
<ns:method1>
<element1><your value1></element1>
<element2><your value2></element2>
<element3><your value3></element3>
</ns:method1>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:method2>
<element1><your value1></element1>
<element2><your value2></element2>
<element3><your value3></element3>
</ns1:method2>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now, to achieve this I have use alternate approach as below:

```
from suds.client import Client

client = Client(URL2)

client.service.method2(element1 = 'value1',element2 = 'value2',element3 = 'value3',)
```

but it gives me **'suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Fault occurred while processing.'**

My concern is, here method1 doing some authentication stuff using URL1 but not able to set headers in SOAP request. Any small help will be appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be problem with parsing the arguments.

How is the output when you substitue the last command with following one:

```
print client
```

So you code should look like:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(URL2)
```